# PHP - How to remove a user from the database MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, delete-row

I created a table where users are discharged from the database. Each user has a row and next to it is a button for deleting a user from the database. The problem is that I do not know how to do to really removed the particular user from the database when I click on a specific button. I have no idea how to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"pl-PL\">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Rezultat zapytania</title>
    <style>
    #container {
      max-width: 1000px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <table width="1000" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#d5d5d5"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <?php
        require_once "connect.php";
        $baza = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name); //Połączenie z bazą danych
        $sql = "SELECT id, user, pass, email FROM users";
        $result = $baza->query($sql);
        $ile = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "znaleziono: ".$ile."<br /><br />";
if ($ile>=1)
{
echo<<<END
<td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5"></td>
<td width="50" align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5">IDUsera</td>
<td width="20" align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5">NazwaUsera</td>
<td width="20" align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5">HasloUsera</td>
<td width="20" align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5">EmailUsera</td>
</tr><tr>
END;
}

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $ile; $i++)
    {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $a1 = $row['id'];
        $a2 = $row['user'];
        $a3 = $row['pass'];
        $a4 = $row['email'];

echo<<<END
<td width="50" align="center"><a class="button_red" href="delete_user.php">Delete</a></td>
<td width="50" align="center">$a1</td>
<td width="100" align="center">$a2</td>
<td width="100" align="center">$a3</td>
<td width="100" align="center">$a4</td>
</tr><tr>
END;

    }


?>


</tr></table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basic syntax: `DELETE FROM table WHERE col_x = ?` - Did you try/search for anything? *Honestly now*. Edit: This is a question; I hope it gets answered (by you). So, did you?

Comment: You can perform al hard delete as mentioned by @Fred-ii- but also you can create a column named deleted, when the value == 1 you don't show it in your results.

Comment: You need to pass the id to the `delete_user.php` using `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Since you are using `<a>` tag, it would be `$_GET`

Comment: ...using a prepared statement of course ;-)

Comment: Maybe try this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp in particular.

Comment: IMHO, the question is too broad; try something then come back when you have difficulties with code you tried. In doing so, you would have learned something in the process.

Comment: Okay, problem solved! I made a reference to the file in which everything I did. I did this by $_GET

Comment: ...great, glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a <td> tag in <tr>
 <td><a href="del.php?user_id={$id}">DEL USER</a></td>

/* del.php */

$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
// you can add a sql injection filter
$sql = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id = {$user_id}';
$result = $baza->query($sql);
```

Comment: this is incorrect and you're also leaving them open to an SQL injection. The OP is using the mysqli_ api, not mysql_; those different apis do not intermix. You need to adjust your answer. Edit: This comment as per original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41409777/1

Comment: This snippet should not be used by researchers as it is not using secure practices.